# Django: Getting a Python encoding error when handling HTTP response in Latin1?

Tags: python, django, encoding, character-encoding

I'm working in Django, and using urllib2 and simplejson to parse some information from an API.

The problem is that the API returns information in the Latin-1 encoding, and just once in a while there's a character in there that causes Django to crash horribly with an encoding error. This is my code:

```
get_person_id_url = "http://www.domain.com/api/get?" + \
    "key=KEY&num="+ urllib2.quote(number) + "&always_return=true&output=js"
request = urllib2.Request(get_person_id_url, None, {'Referer': ''})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
results = json.load(response)
person_id = results["person_id"]
```

I know that I can use something like this to turn Latin1 strings into UTF8:

```
responseString = responseString.decode('latin1').encode('utf-8')
```

but it seems this only works on strings, so I'm not completely sure how or where to apply it in the above code. What should I decode and where to trap any errors before they occur?

Unfortunately I don't remember what API call to make to return a character that will crash Django - so I can't do much testing before it goes live. I'm hoping StackOverflow can help... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `response.read()` to get the data of the response. Then in a `try/except` do your latin1 decoding and json loading. In general, Django should never crash if you wrap potentially error-causing operations in exception handlers and take care of them appropriately (at least log them somewhere so you can deal with them at some point in the future).

Comment: Thanks. Can I do something like "response_string = response.read() (do the decoding and encoding) results=json.load(response_string)", or will I need to turn response_string back into an object that simplejson can handle? That was partly my question - how to get it back into simplejson, which has very limited documentation.

Comment: `json.loads` simple takes a string (in Json format). So, for example if your Python string was `s = '{"a": 1}'` then you could do `d = json.loads(s)` and get back a Python dict. Likewise, `s = json.dumps(d)` would produce a json encoded string. I (and I suspect most people) only use the `dumps` and `loads` methods.